# Convert array of dictionaries into a dictionary and init the model

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, alamofire

I'm getting an array of dictionaries from the server. Then I'm trying to convert it to jsonDictionary it seems like I'm doing something wrong. How can I also init my Users model?
Here is the code:

```
func getSearchedUsers(key: String, completion: @escaping(SearchedUsers?) -> Void) {
    if let url = URL(string: baseURL + "search?qerty=\(key)") {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
            if let array = response.result.value as? [[String:Any]] {
                var dictionary = [String:Any]()
                for item in array {
                    for (key, value) in item {
                        dictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the model:

```
class SearchedUsers {
    let id: Int
    let username: String?
    let fullName: String?
    let profilePicture: URL?
    let isPrivate: Bool

    init(data: [String: Any]) {
        id = data["id"] as! Int
        username = data["username"] as? String
        fullName = data["fullName"] as? String
        isPrivate = data["isPrivate"] as! Bool
        profilePicture = data["profilePicUrl"] as? URL
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Here is the response I get:

```
[Result]: SUCCESS: (
    {
    byline = "21.9k followers";
    followerCount = 21911;
    friendshipStatus =         {
        following = 0;
        "incoming_request" = 0;
        "is_bestie" = 0;
        "is_private" = 0;
        "outgoing_request" = 0;
    };
    fullName = "Undefined Variable";
    hasAnonymousProfilePicture = 0;
    id = 8513861541;
    isPrivate = 0;
    isVerified = 0;
    mutualFollowersCount = 0;
    picture = "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/885ac17fe17809de22790f0559f61877/5CD13A1C/t51.2885-19/s150x150/39312159_480582069091253_3011569611268161536_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com";
    pk = 8513861541;
    profilePicId = "1857507164564653723_8513861541";
    profilePicUrl = "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/885ac17fe17809de22790f0559f61877/5CD13A1C/t51.2885-19/s150x150/39312159_480582069091253_3011569611268161536_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com";
    reelAutoArchive = on;
    username = "i_am_variable";
},
    {
    byline = "467 followers";
    followerCount = 467;
    friendshipStatus =         {
        following = 0;
        "incoming_request" = 0;
        "is_bestie" = 0;
        "is_private" = 0;
        "outgoing_request" = 0;
    };
    fullName = undefined;
    hasAnonymousProfilePicture = 0;
    id = 8657882817;
    isPrivate = 0;
    isVerified = 0;
    latestReelMedia = 1547794887;
    mutualFollowersCount = 0;
    picture = "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fb3c992c899aa269bdce2c4c1db8575b/5CD068BA/t51.2885-19/s150x150/46378106_2062632390480778_1266491662662631424_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com";
    pk = 8657882817;
    profilePicId = "1931972067016763185_8657882817";
    profilePicUrl = "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fb3c992c899aa269bdce2c4c1db8575b/5CD068BA/t51.2885-19/s150x150/46378106_2062632390480778_1266491662662631424_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com";
    reelAutoArchive = on;
    username = "undefi.ned";
})
```

It's an array of dictionaries, I need to parse it in a proper way. That's my main issue.

Comment: What is the output/result? Any error message?

Comment: Would be nice if you add example code of your json. Anyway, are you using Swift 4+? Then you can try to search something about `Codable`

Comment: This is a great blog post about JSON parsing - maybe you wanna start with the basics: https://medium.com/@nimjea/json-parsing-in-swift-2498099b78f. It uses the out of the box JSON Encoding/Decoding tools provided by iOS. IMHO there is no need to use an external library for that.

Comment: @EmmaVagradyan, If you post some of your response data in your post then it becomes easy for others to help you.

Comment: @Kuldeep, please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to parse dictionary, then you should know how to make one ;) There are tools out there to make your own model class, like: http://www.jsoncafe.com/

**EDIT**: As suggested by Robert in the comment section below, you can learn `Decodable`.

You can use that to give yourself an idea how a model class could or should look like. Use it however you like. In a decent project, there could be tons of data, and you don't want to make a class model out of it especially if you're the only one handling the iOS project.

So we suppose, we have this json data, based on your post:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "dd",
    "fullName": "dd",
    "profilePicture": "ddd",
    "isPrivate": true
}
```

We could make a model out of it like so:

```
//
//  UserRootClass.swift
//  Model Generated using http://www.jsoncafe.com/
//  Created on January 18, 2019

import Foundation

class UserRootClass : NSObject {

    var fullName : String!
    var id : Int!
    var isPrivate : Bool!
    var profilePicture : String!
    var username : String!


    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
        fullName = dictionary["fullName"] as? String
        id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
        isPrivate = dictionary["isPrivate"] as? Bool
        profilePicture = dictionary["profilePicture"] as? String
        username = dictionary["username"] as? String
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
     */
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
    {
        var dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if fullName != nil{
            dictionary["fullName"] = fullName
        }
        if id != nil{
            dictionary["id"] = id
        }
        if isPrivate != nil{
            dictionary["isPrivate"] = isPrivate
        }
        if profilePicture != nil{
            dictionary["profilePicture"] = profilePicture
        }
        if username != nil{
            dictionary["username"] = username
        }
        return dictionary
    }

}
```

The model class above was made using the tool I gave above, but I removed the `NSCoding` protocol methods.

I hope this helps! Good luck and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: If you suppose that json looks like that, you can also suppose that she’s using the newest version of Swift so you should suggest struct conforming to `Decodable`

Comment: Right. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: i know how to init from dictionary, bu my issue is that I get an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary, and I don't know how to convert into a dictionary in a proper way. I've posted the way I do it in the question, but it doesn't work as need. 
The response I get has the following type `[{"key":"value"}]`

Comment: And yes, I use Swift 4.2, thank for suggestion @RobertDresler

Answer (score 0):

You can use Decodable if you have Struct instead of Class for easy parsing. Here is the example in Alamofire 5.0

```
struct SearchedUsers: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let username: String?
    let fullName: String?
    let profilePicture: URL?
    let isPrivate: Bool
}

AF.request("http://url_endpoint/").responseData { response in
            do {
                // data we are getting from network request
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode([SearchedUsers].self, from: response.data!)

            } catch { print(error) }
        }
```